# Django Rest Framework Integrity Error at NOT NULL constraint fail

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i'm trying to post a transaction via django rest framework, however it shows error in django log as below:

*IntegrityError at /api/item_trans/
NOT NULL constraint failed: chemstore_itemtransaction.bin_code_id*

it has no problem if I post the same data from the Django admin web.
therefore I suppose the problem has happened at DRF

any help is welcome, thank you

models.py

```
class BinLocation(models.Model):
    bin_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bin_code

    class Meta:
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['bin_code'])]


class ItemMaster(models.Model):
    item_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    long_desc = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    helper_qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_code

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Item"
        verbose_name_plural = "Items"
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['item_code'])]


class ItemTransaction(models.Model):
    # trace_code YYMMDDXXXX where XXXX is random generated
    trace_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False)
    item_code = models.ForeignKey(
        ItemMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', blank=False, null=False)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    qty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=4)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    action = models.CharField(
        max_length=1, choices=ACTION, blank=False, null=False)
    bin_code = models.ForeignKey(
        BinLocation, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False)
    remarks = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.trace_code} {self.datetime} {self.item_code} {dict(ACTION)[self.action]} {self.qty} {self.unit} {self.bin_code}"
```

serializers.py

```
class ItemMasterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemMaster
        fields = '__all__'


class ItemTransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item_code = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='item_code',
        read_only=True
    )

    bin_code = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='bin_code',
        read_only=True,
        allow_null=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ItemTransaction
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use 2 fields, one for reading data and the other for creating and updating your data with its source to the main. In your case you could try this:

```
class ItemTransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item_code_id = ItemMasterSerializer(read_only=True)
    item_code = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            queryset=ItemMaster.objects.all(),
            write_only=True,
            source='item_code_id'
        )
    
    bin_code_id = BinLocationSerializer(read_only=True
    bin_code = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
            queryset= BinLocation.objects.all(),
            write_only=True,
            source='bin_code_id'
        )
```

Since you have **null=False** in both of your ForeignKeys, DRF expects the corresponding ID. You seem to be getting the error NOT NULL constraint because you are not passing the ID in DRF. So you need to fix that for both bin_code_id and the item_code_id.

Comment: thankyou Persia, in that case I've removed the null = false for both ForeignKey for testing, then if I empty the ItemTransactionSerializer class, it actually works pretty well.  However, what if I need to use the item_code and bin_code instead of the key for posting the transaction?  that's the reason I used SlugRelatedField, but it failed on posting...  do you know how?

Comment: Well I believe the solution I gave above should pretty work well when you need to use the item_code and the bin_code. I think the names item_code_id and bin_code_id might have thrown you off. In fact, they are not id's but are actually referencing your item_code and bin_code. So maybe you can rename them item_code_number and bin_code_number. These are the serializer fields that will be used to display your data in the api and the item_code and bin_code will act as fields for reading and updating. Note that these will not show up in your API data object because of the write_only=True attribute.

Comment: thx Persia, after all, I've used SlugRelatedField to solve the problem.  since ModelViewSet has done many things behind the scene, it is somewhat confusing to a newbie, sorry for a stupid question asked.

Comment: No problem Steven. We are all just learning everyday tbh.